# Get Substr including year in a Movie Title String

Tags: php

I have movie titles

```
The Abandoned 2015 480p Reformed
The Lady in the Car with Glasses and a Gun 2015 BluRay 720p
Rise of the Footsoldier Part II (2015) 720p
```

All i want is movie title and year, example in the first title just `The Abandoned 2015`. I have a regex that find year in title example it return 2015 in all the above titles, when i use `strpos(movietitle,year)` returns position of a year in the title but when i use `substr(movietitle,0,-(yearpos))` does not give me a title and year excluding anything follows.

anyone with an approach to do this. There are many titles with different string lengths.

Here is my script trying to get Title and Year for one of them but failed to give me what i needed..

```
$str = "Suffragette 2015 DVDSCR Webz";

if (preg_match('/(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
}else{
    $year = "";
}

if($year != ""){
   $pos = strpos($str,$year);
   echo substr($str,0,-($pos)); //Fail...
}
```

Comment: Is it a string ? an object ? an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this Solution..

```
$movt = "Paranormal Activity The Ghost Dimension 2015 720p BluRay x265 HEVC RMTeam";
$arrz = array("(",")");
$str = str_replace($arrz,'',$movt);

if (preg_match('/(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
}else{
    $year = "";
}

if($year != ""){
$pos = strpos($str,$year);
$ext = strlen(substr($str,($pos+5)));
echo substr($str,0,strlen($str)-$ext);
}
```

Gives

```
Paranormal Activity The Ghost Dimension 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "Suffragette 2015 DVDSCR Webz";

if (preg_match('/(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
}else{
    $year = "";
}

if($year != ""){
    $pos = strpos($str,$year);

    // Add 5 to $pos because " 2015" have 5 characters
    echo substr($str,0, (5 + $pos));
}
```

This works for your example... The result would be `Suffragette 2015`, but if your title have any year on it, the result of the script would be an incomplete title.

---

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the three things you've got up top, seems to work for them (granted it is only 3 test cases)

```
<?php
$titles = array(
    "The Abandoned 2015 480p Reformed",
    "The Lady in the Car with Glasses and a Gun 2015 BluRay 720p",
    "Rise of the Footsoldier Part II (2015) 720p"
);
//List of titles to look through.
$reg = '/([\w\s]+)\(?([0-9]{4})\)?/';
foreach($titles as $title){
    if(preg_match($reg,$title,$matches)){
        //If we get a match, keep going
        echo $matches[1]. ' ' . $matches[2].'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```